# Is the Law SE an appropriate place to ask about security?

Tags: discussion, scope

Let's say a user was to ask about how to reduce crime in his street or how to reduce shoplifting in his/her business, is this the right place to ask about it?
It is not about questioning on what is legal to do or not, just what can be (legally) done to improve security.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  For physical security you might try [DIY.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) or [HardwareRecs.SE](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Those SEs are more for installing cameras or alarms. I don't think that they would work for the social aspect of violence. Let's say that someone had a question like "How to prevent my son from being bullied at school?" (Mind that an actual question would be more developed) Generally both law or electronic security do not work to prevent such kind of violence.

Comment: Well for that particular question there's [parenting.se].  Of course there's not a Stack Exchange for everything.  In any case, I can't imagine how questions of the type you describe could be on-topic at [law.se].

Answer (score 0):

From the original question author:

Security question:

Can it be solved using a device that is not a weapon?

- Yes: DIY.SE
- No: Is the target a child?

  - Yes: Parenting.SE
  - No: Is it in the work place?

    - Yes: Workplace.SE
    - No: Martial Arts.SE